# Error 400 when cloning GEE script locally

Tags: google-earth-engine, github

I need to modify google earth engine (GEE) scripts on my mac. I was hoping to run git clone https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/... to get a local copy. Unfortunately, I get this response after a query for username and password unable to access 'https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/...': The requested URL returned error: 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your locally cached password credentials for accessing git on `googlesource.com` may need to be refreshed. You can reset your credentials by navigating to your root repository:

`https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/USERNAME/`

and then click the "Generate Password" link.

Alternatively, you can navigate directly to:

`https://www.googlesource.com/new-password`

This will present you with instructions for completing an OAuth authentication workflow which will store credentials on your local machine that will allow access to your git repositories stored on googlesource.com.

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charm. Was not aware of the local git credentials.

Comment: Note for windows users... the powershell commands it gives you are semi broken. Substitute %USERPROFILE% for C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME. The command that appends to .gitcookies is also wrong. Although `t is the [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.4) for tab, it doesn't work and produces a messed up gitcookies. Edit gitcookies in notepad and make the newly appended credential be a single line with tab-delimited fields. OR, just use the git bash terminal and the linux commands work fine.